# Starting a separate exe and exiting the current programm

Tags: c#

I am trying to start a second exe-program from within a c# program.
This is my current code:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\HASy-Diag.exe";
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "git-synchro " + args[1];
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.Start();
```

But here is the catch: I want to exit my program right after I started the second exe.

The point is, that I have to do some asynchronous work, which cannot be in the same *process* as the programm. Note here, that is has to be in another process, not another thread. The reason is, that I want to do some work next to a build from an IDE. Running commands before and after the build is implemented in that IDE. The IDE (Keil here) waits, until the prebuild-process is finished (thats why I have to stop it) and then starts to build.

I want to retrieve information while the IDE builds the project (to essentially save time). So I want to start a new process from within a process.

is that possible? Any process I start with then given code above does not execute if you exit the full program. This code only executes if I have `p.waitForExit()` in the code.

Comment: This should work fine.  What happens if you insert a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` after `Process.Start`?

Comment: How do you exit your current program?

Comment: Aside from what the other commenters already mentioned, what if you try to start a "harmless" program like notepad.exe? Will it execute even when you exit your program immediately after starting it? (This is an attempt to figure out whether HASy-Diag.exe has some weird interaction/dependence with your running program...)

Comment: was totally my fault, had some errors in the code, solution has nothing to do with this process but with debugging my other code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use p.WaitForExit with parameter - pass 0 miliseconds, so your app will not wait but continue normally:

```
p.WaitForExit(0);
```

This method returns true if process ended and false if it is still in progress, but in your case it will not matter.